# How to use Pageable as get-query parameter in spring-data-rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have a simple query controller that takes query parameters (as `Person` dto) and a `Pageable`:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
   @GetMapping("/persons")
   public Object search(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable pageable, Person form) {
       repository.findAll(form, pageable);
   }
}
```

The pageable can take both `sort` and `page` parameters as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/persons?sort=age,desc&page=5
```

Problem: for the sort, I want to add order hints like `NULLS_LAST` or `NULLS_FIRST`.

Question: how can I achieve this using query params too?

Comment: there is a property to put in application.properties : spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering=last/first. but may be you want to apply it dynamically?

Comment: What's the default value for this? But indeed I'd like to apply this dynamically per property (some properties I want to sort nulls_last by default, and some nulls_first).

Comment: default is none. i will try to provide you a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify `Pageable` object like this (method to put in your controller for example). This is an example with one sort field, but you can loop on all fields and modify `nullsLast/nullsFirst` in the same way. Please try :

```
private Pageable customSort(Pageable pageable) {
    Sort sort = pageable.getSort();
    Order order = sort.iterator().next();
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    // nullsFirst or nullsLast
    orders.add(new Order(order.getDirection(),order.getProperty()).nullsFirst());
    return PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by(orders));
}
```

Comment: So as there is no frontend-only solution, this works great!

Answer (score -1):

Try to do something like :

```
pageable.getSort().and(Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "age", Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_LAST)));
```