# Spring Pageable null first with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-data-rest, pageable

In my app I want to add to my pageable object I want to add order null first for selected attribute. I have followed this advice on stack overflow:
[How to use Pageable as get-query parameter in spring-data-rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873119/how-to-use-pageable-as-get-query-parameter-in-spring-data-rest)

Like this:

```
private Pageable customSort(Pageable pageable) {
    Sort sort = pageable.getSort();
    Order order = sort.iterator().next();
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    orders.add(new Order(order.getDirection(),order.getProperty()).nullsFirst());
    return PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by(orders));
}
```

But my problem is that we use SQL Server database which does not support nulls first sorting. (as you can see here: [TSQL ORDER BY with nulls first or last (at bottom or top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986683/tsql-order-by-with-nulls-first-or-last-at-bottom-or-top/42987011))

Is there any workaround how to modify pageable request for SQL Server database?

Comment: Have you actually tried this code to see the results? I suspect that the JPA dialect simulates this with some tricks (or Spring Data JPA does it).

Comment: Yes i have tried it, it looks like it is ommited in sql result:     ...order by
myobject.attribute desc offset 0 rows fetch next ? rows only

Comment: Please add your repository and confiugration to your question.